# Passing a string to a function to output it (C++)

Tags: c++, string, function

"Writing something in C++ to create a square wave in Assembly for a microprocessor.
Anyway, my layout is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string> 

using namespace std;




void code_calc(float cyc, float cyc_high, float cyc_low, string prt, string pncnf, string pnhgh, char prtlttr) {
    ofstream outfile("sqrwv.txt");
    if (outfile.is_open()) {
        cout << "\n\nWriting to file...\n\n"<<prt<<pncnf<<cyc_low;
        outfile << "Sqrwv   MOVLW   0x02            ; Crude count variable\n"
                <<  "   MOVWF   count4          ; Store in COUNT4 to generate wait of 0.5s\n"
                <<  "   BSF STATUS, RP0     ;\n"
                <<  "   BCF STATUS, RP1     ; Select bank 1\n"
                <<  "   MOVLW   B'"<<pncnf<<"'      ; Write / output only on pin 1\n"
                <<  "   MOVWF   TRIS"<<prtlttr<< "          ; so portb is now(wwww wwww)\n"
                <<  "sqhigh BCF STATUS, RP0     ;\n"
                <<  "   BCF STATUS, RP1     ; Select bank 0\n"
                <<  "   BSF "<<prt<<", "<<pnhgh<<"      ; Set pin 1 of port B high\n"
                <<  "   CALL    Delay           ; Wait 0.1s\n"
                <<  "   DECFSZ  count4, 1       ; Decrement COUNT4 to generate\n"
                <<  "   GOTO    sqhigh          ; a flat high signal of 0.5s\n"
                <<  "   MOVLW   0x02            ; Crude count variable again\n"
                <<  "   MOVWF   count5          ; \n"
                <<  "sqlow  NOP             ; NOP to ensure correct cycles on high and low\n"
                <<  "   NOP             ; mirroring the BCFs in HIGH\n"
                <<  "   BCF "<<prt<<", "<<pnhgh<<"      ; Set pin 1 of port B low\n"
                <<  "   NOP             ;\n"
                <<  "   NOP             ;\n"
                <<  "   NOP             ; 93 cycles low\n"
                <<  "   CALL    Delay           ; Wait 0.1s\n"
                <<  "   DECFSZ  count5, 1       ; Decrement COUNT4 to generate a flat low signal\n"
                <<  "   GOTO    sqlow           ; Repeat 4 more times, giving 0.5s\n"
                <<  "   GOTO    Sqrwv           ; If count4 is now zero, just go back to high - forever 83 counts\n";
        outfile.close();
    } 
    else cout << "Couldn't open file. Try again.";
}

// outputs menu text when called 
void menu_bs() {
    cout << "       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::\n"
        << "        :: Square Wave Generator with Assembly ::\n"        // initiate the menu
        << "        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::\n\n"
        << "Follow the instructions in the list, "
        << "and check for output in sqrwv.txt\n\n"
        << "1.  Some important information\n"
        << "2.  Enter your clock speed\n"           // give the user various options
        << "3.  Enter your wave period\n"
        << "4.  Or Enter your wave frequency\n"
        << "5.  Configure your port and pins\n"
        << "6.  Enter your duty cycle\n"
        << "7.  Generate your code\n"
        << "8.  Exit\n\n"           // allow the user to exit using the
        << "Choice: \n";            
}


void menu() {
    while (1) {
        system("CLS");                  
        char select[1];                         // use as menu select variable 
        menu_bs();
        unsigned long long int speed;
        float time;
        float cycle;
        float cycle_high;
        float cycle_low;
        float period;
        float frequency;
        float duty;
        char portletter;
        string port;
        string pinconf;
        string pinhigh;
        cin >> select;
        if (select[0] == '1')
        {
            system("CLS");
            cin.ignore();
            cout << "There are a few things that you should note: \n"
                << "- Designed for use with P16F877A\n"
                << "- You can enter a delay time of 3.4e +/- 38\n"
                << "- For cycle counts <=1277, you only need to reserve for count1\n"
                << "- For cycle counts <=261125, you need to reserve both count1 and count2\n"
                << "- For cycle counts <=62620865, you need to reserve count1, count2 and count3\n"
                << "- The upper cycle limit for the code created is 62620861 cycles\n"
                << "    - This would give a delay of about 62 seconds on a 1MHz clock\n";
            system("PAUSE");
            system("CLS");
        }
        if (select[0] == '2')
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "Your clock speed\n\n";
            cout << "Enter your clock speed in integer form: e.g. 5000000\n\n";
            cin >> speed;
            cout << "\n\nYou chose " << speed << "\n\n";
            system("PAUSE");
            system("CLS");
        }

        else if (select[0] == '3')
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "Your wave period\n\n";
            cout << "Enter your wave period in decimal form or integer: 3.5\n\n";
            cin >> time;
            cout << "\n\n";
            cycle = time * speed;
            cout << "\n\nYou chose a period of " << time << "s\n\n";
            cout << "This corresponds to " << cycle << " cycles for one period.\n\n";
            system("PAUSE");
            system("CLS");
        }
        else if (select[0] == '4')
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "Your wave frequency\n\n";
            cout << "Enter your wave frequency in decmial form or integer: 0.2\n\n";
            cin >> time;
            cout << "\n\n";
            cycle = speed / time;
            cout << "\n\nYou chose a frequency of " << time << "Hz\n\n";
            cout << "This corresponds to " << cycle << " cycles for your frequency\n\n";
            system("PAUSE");
            system("CLS");
        }
        else if (select[0] == '5')
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "Your port configuration\n\n";
            cout << "Enter one port which you'd like to mess with: e.g. PORTA, PORTB, PORTC\n\n";
            cin.ignore();
            getline(cin, port);
            cout << "\n\n";
            cout << "Now enter the write read configuration of the pins on your port: \n e.g. 00000000 = write all, 00001111 = write four, read 4\n\n";
            getline(cin, pinconf);
            cout << "\n\n";
            cout << "Now enter the pin you'd like to toggle high/low: e.g. 1-7\n\n";
            getline(cin, pinhigh);
            pinhigh = pinhigh;
            portletter = port.at(4);
            if (pinconf.length() == 8 && port.length() == 5) {
                cout << "\n\nYou're configured to: " << port << "(" << pinconf << ")\n\n";
                cout << "You'll be using the TRIS" << port.at(4) << " register and will be toggling pin " << pinhigh<<endl<<endl;
            } else  cout << "\n\nYour port should be five characters long and your pin \nconfiguration should be eight characters because you have \neight pins. Try again.\n\n";
            system("PAUSE");
            system("CLS");
        }
        else if (select[0] == '6')
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << "Your wave duty cycle\n\n";
            cout << "Enter your duty cycle as a decmial (not percentage): e.g. 50% duty cycle = 0.5\n\n";
            cin >> duty;
            cout << "\n\n";
            if (duty >= 1 || duty <= 0) {
                cout << "\n\nYou can't have a duty cycle greater than or less than 100% or 0% respectively.\n\n";
                system("PAUSE");
                system("CLS");
            }
            else {
                cycle_high = cycle * duty;
                cycle_low = cycle * (1 - duty);
                cout << "\n\nYou chose a duty cycle of " << duty * 100 << "%\n\n";
                cout << "This corresponds to " << cycle_high << " cycles for your logic high.\n";
                cout << "This corresponds to " << cycle_low << " cycles for your logic low.\n\n";
                system("PAUSE");
                system("CLS");
            }
        }
        else if (select[0] == '7')
        {
            system("CLS");
            cout << cycle << cycle_high << port << pinconf;
            code_calc(cycle, cycle_high, cycle_low, port, pinconf, pinhigh, portletter);
            system("PAUSE");
            system("CLS");
        }
        else if (select[0] == '8')                  // quit option
        {
            system("CLS");
            exit(0);
            system("PAUSE");
            system("CLS");
        }
        else 
        {                                   
            system("CLS");
            cout << "You have entered an invalid input, please try again.\n";
            cout << "Try to enter a number corresponding to the menu item.\n";
            system("PAUSE");
            system("CLS");
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    menu();
}
```

If I call the function inside one of the previous `if` statements where the `a, ... g` variables are called, it 'sort-of' works. However, I thought because I initiated the variables at the beginning of the `while` loop, their scope was for the WHOLE of that `while` loop, inside or outside of `if` statements.

So, currently my variables are not being passed to my `wv_calc()` function, and as a result, my code is absent of the inline variables `a, b, ..., g`.

Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your question is about the code with the `while` loop. Why did you post the function instead?

Comment: Try using more meaningful variable names. My guess is you reused the variables.

Comment: The while loop code is self-explanatory, I thought somebody would be able to spot a mistake with variable scopes/passing variables, but I'll post the `while` code now.

Comment: `wv_calc` doesn't even use most of the variables that you pass.

Comment: @Barmar, the variable names are for the simplicity of the post, my actual program has variable names that reference the number of cycles, the frequency, duty and period, etc.

Comment: @Barmar it will once I've fixed this problem. It's senseless to build further functionality to a function which doesn't receive any of the variables it asks for.

Comment: can you post your main() and menu(). And what do you mean by "sort of"? You need to be more specific. What are the outputs? What are the variable definitions in main() and menu()?

Comment: what is expected output `if(user_selected==a)` twice before finally calling `if(user_selected==x)` . Because only the most recent value of a will be passed to  `wv_calc` ?

Comment: @lmsavk Please post a [MCVE], otherwise it's not possible to diagnose your problem.

Comment: Hopefully amended(?) I was just trying to avoid people having to read through lines and lines of code - apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking at your code, a lot of your problems are due to bad organization of code.

For instance lets assume you set `select == 2` do you see what would be the sequence of execution. It would be as follows and what do you think gets passed into `cycle,cycle_high, cycle_low, port and pinconf`. They are uninitialized so the values they carry are implementation dependent

```
if (select[0]=='2'){
            system("CLS");
            wv_calc(cycle, cycle_high, cycle_low, port, pinconf, pinhigh, portletter);
            system("PAUSE");
            system("CLS");
```

For instance a user of your program would have to know to always set `select == '1'` to initialize `port, pinconf, pinhigh, portletter` before setting `select = '2'`. This may be obvious to you but not so to the compiler which generates code the way you write it.

```
 if (select[0]=='1'){
            system("CLS");
            cin.ignore();
            getline(cin, port);
    getline(cin, port);
                getline(cin, pinconf);
                getline(cin, pinhigh);
                portletter = port.at(4);
```

Also I don't see where values of `cycle, cycle_high, cycle_low` are being set. They definitely are not being set at all before the call to `wv_calc`

**Updated**

Here's what you need to do :

```
void menu() {
    float time;
    float cycle;
    float cycle_high;
    float cycle_low;
    float period;
    float frequency;
    float duty;
    unsigned long long int speed;
    char portletter;
    string port;
    string pinconf;
    string pinhigh;

    while (1) {
        system("CLS");
        //char select[1];       //why do you need an array here
        char select;
        menu_bs();


        cin >> select;
....
....
```

Comment: "I understand that according to the above code cycle, cycle_high and cycle_low are not initialised, but they are elsewhere in the menu - in other if statements." 
I should clarify that by saying I haven't shown the code where they're initialised... But, everybody seems to be so confused by my post, I might as well just put the complete code up.

Comment: I see your problem. Your variables are local to the while loop. So they get recreated each time the while loop executes afresh. As a result their previous values are lost. Check my updated answer. As an aside you cannot assume that the user won't jump to option 7 right away. If that happens then `cycle, cycle_high, cycle_low` are just going to be a load of junk

Comment: Options 2,3,4,5 are not really options in your case. They are required for options 6 and 7 to work. Try to reorganize the code.

Comment: Hey Prab, figured it was something like this, thanks for spotting it. This program is only going to be used by me (and maybe some other electronic engineers), so the input validation isn't really necessary; I know it's bad programming practice, but nobody is going to entering 7 and expecting code that will compile. Thanks again.